# Como adicionar Padding no Select

Tags: html, bootstrap

Eu coloquei um padding de 30px, o select realmente fica maior mas ele não aparece nada.

```css
select.custom{
    padding: 30px!important;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance:none;
}
select.custom option{
    padding: 30px!important;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-md-12">
<select class="form-control custom">
<option>AAAAAAAAAAAAAA</option>
</select>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Guilherme, o que aconteceu no seu caso é que o Boostrap tem estilos próprios e o seu padding com important está empurrando o texto de tal forma que ele some.

Experimentei aumentar a altura usando important no seu select.custom e passou a aparecer o texto:

```
height:80px!important;
```

E para aparecer a setinha tradicional do select basta você remover dos seus estilos custom as linhas:

```
-moz-appearance: none;
-webkit-appearance:none;
```